# TikZ, use "shift" with perpendicular coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

TikZ allows this use of `shift`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (a0) at (4,3);
\coordinate (a1) at (5,2);
\coordinate (a2) at (6,8);

\draw (a1) -- ([shift={(1,0.5)}]a2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but for example this use

```
\draw (a1) -- ([shift={(1,0.5)}](a2 |- a0));
```

generates an error.

The definition of a `coordinate` in `(a2 |- a0)` would solve the issue. But is there a way to use `shift` directly along with perpendicular coordinates?

Comment: `\draw (a1) -- ([shift={(1,0.5)}]a2 |- a0);` ?

Comment: @esdd It works, thank you! If you want, you can write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `([shift={(1,0.5)}]a2 |- a0)` to shift the coordinate directly.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines](3,1)grid(8,10);

\coordinate (a0) at (4,3);
\coordinate (a1) at (5,2);
\coordinate (a2) at (6,8);

\draw (a1) -- ([shift={(1,0.5)}]a2 |- a0);

\foreach \i in {0,1,2}{%
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label=above:a\i] at (a\i){};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```